# Convert one column to rows and columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, transpose, data-wrangling

I keep running into this use and I haven't found a good solution.  I am asking for a solution in python, but a solution in R would also be helpful.

I've been getting data that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': ['Bob', '101', 'First Street', '', 'Sue', '102', 'Second Street', '', 'Alex' , '200', 'Third Street', '']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


             Col1
0             Bob
1             101
3
4             Sue
5             102
6   Second Street
7
8            Alex
9             200
10   Third Street
11
```

The pattern in my real data does repeat like this.  Sometimes there is a blank row (or more than 1), and sometimes there are not any blank rows.  The important part here is that I need to convert this column into a row.

I want the data to look like this.

```
   Name Address         Street
0   Bob     101   First Street
1   Sue     102  Second Street
2  Alex     200   Third Street
```

I have tried playing around with this, but nothing has worked.  My thought was to iterate through a few rows at a time, assign the values to the appropriate column, and just build a data frame row by row.

```
x = len(df['Col1'])
holder = pd.DataFrame()
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

while x < 4:
    temp = df.iloc[:5]
    holder['Name'] = temp['Col1'].iloc[0]
    holder['Address'] = temp['Col1'].iloc[1]
    holder['Street'] = temp['Col1'].iloc[2]

    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, holder])

    df = temp[5:]
    df.reset_index()

    holder = pd.DataFrame()

    x = len(df['Col1'])


new_df.head(10)
```

Comment: It's possible if the people are separated by blank lines. Otherwise, it will be difficult to determine which lines can be merged.

Comment: Yep, with blank rows, it's pretty easy to assign a group like `dat$grp <- cumsum(dat$Col1 == "")` (in R for instance), but if there aren't clear breaks, it's really tough.

Comment: Your example print-out of the data is missing row #2, which makes it look even harder than it is.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`,

```
data <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c('Bob', '101', 'First Street', '', 'Sue', '102', 'Second Street', '', 'Alex' , '200', 'Third Street', '')
)

k<-which(grepl("Street", data$Col1) == TRUE)
j <- k-1
i <- k-2
data.frame(
  Name = data[i,],
  Adress = data[j,],
  Street = data[k,]
)

  Name Adress        Street
1  Bob    101  First Street
2  Sue    102 Second Street
3 Alex    200  Third Street
```

Or, if `Street` not ends with `Street` but `Adress` are always a number, you can also try

```
j <- which(apply(data, 1, function(x) !is.na(as.numeric(x)) ))
i <- j-1
k <- j+1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Python3

In Python 3, you can convert your DataFrame into an array and then reshape it.

```py
n = df.shape[0]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=df.to_numpy().reshape((n//4, 4), order='C'),
    columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Street', 'Empty'])
```

This produces for your sample data this:

```
   Name Address         Street Empty
0   Bob     101   First Street      
1   Sue     102  Second Street      
2  Alex     200   Third Street
```

If you like you can remove the last column:

```py
df2 = df2.drop(['Empty'], axis=1)
```

```
   Name Address         Street
0   Bob     101   First Street
1   Sue     102  Second Street
2  Alex     200   Third Street
```

#### One-liner code

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame(data=df.to_numpy().reshape((df.shape[0]//4, 4), order='C' ), columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Street', 'Empty']).drop(['Empty'], axis=1)
```

```
   Name Address         Street
0   Bob     101   First Street
1   Sue     102  Second Street
2  Alex     200   Third Street
```

Answer (score 0):

In python i believe this may help u.

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2
  3 data = {'Col1': ['Bob', '101', 'First Street', '', 'Sue', '102', 'Second Street', '', 'Alex' , '200', 'Third Street', '']}
  4
  5 var = list(data.values())[0]
  6 var2 = []
  7 for aux in range(int(len(var)/4)):
  8     var2.append(var[aux*4: aux*4+3])
  9 data = pd.DataFrame(var2, columns=['Name', 'Address','Street',])
 10 print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another R solution. This solution is based on the `tidyverse` package. The example data frame `data` is from Park's post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69833814/7669809).

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(ID = cumsum(Col1 %in% "")) %>%
  filter(!Col1 %in% "") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Type = case_when(
    row_number() == 1L        ~"Name",
    row_number() == 2L        ~"Address",
    row_number() == 3L        ~"Street",
    TRUE                      ~NA_character_
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Type", values_from = "Col1") %>%
  ungroup()
data2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID Name  Address Street       
#   <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr>        
# 1     0 Bob   101     First Street 
# 2     1 Sue   102     Second Street
# 3     2 Alex  200     Third Street
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of the DataFrame are reshaped by unknown rows and 4 columns, then the first 3 columns of the entire array are taken out by slicing and converted into a DataFrame, and finally the columns of DataFrame are reset by set_axis

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 4)[:, :-1])\
     .set_axis(['Name', 'Address', 'Street'], axis=1)
result
>>>

    Name   Address  Street
0   Bob      101    First Street
1   Sue      102    Second Street
2   Alex     200    Third Street
```